# How to re-number T-SQL's system auto-increment Identity column?

Tags: sql, primary-key, auto-increment

I have an auto-increment primary key in a SQL table lets say table look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [Table] (--Identifier contains a space and uses a reserved keyword.
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL ,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [PK__Table] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
);

ID  |  Name|
1     John
2     Jack
3     Bill 
4     Joe
```

Then I delete row 2 Jack:

```
ID  |  Name|
1     John
3     Bill 
4     Joe
```

And what I want to achieve is to change id column so the table will look like this

```
ID  |  Name|
1     John
2     Bill 
3     Joe
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Yes there are ways to do it, but as a rule of thumb, I think you shouldn't alter primary keys

Comment: if there are referencing records on the primary key, you can't delete and alter it.

Comment: have you thought what will happen to tables depending upon PK [ID] of this particular table?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607998/using-a-sort-order-column-in-a-database-table/8608085#8608085  but I would suggest not changing a primary key as others have.  Ask yourslef why do you care about the numbers being sequential?  Does it REALLY matter? probably not so why bother with the update?

Comment: @JW웃, you could disable the constraints, do the update, and re-enable them but it would be a risky operation for little (if any) benefit

Comment: lets say it is a single table and no other table is connected to this particular table.The problem is that in my java code im highlighting JTable columns according to column id and when some record is deleted it is highlited wrong

Comment: @JurajŽiKoSlavíček do you mean a different style for even/odd rows? if so, use the row number not the primary key

Comment: @vc74 no its something like desktop livescore application.Im parsing xml feed and when current score in some lets say football match is changed i highlight column with that match

Comment: maybe its good to mention that im working with hibernate i forgot to add it to tags

Answer (score 4):

I will never do that but you can:

1. create a new autoincrement primary key named ID2
2. delete ID column
3. rename ID2 column as ID

Comment: Agreed, would never do this in production, but nice, easy and super simple answer

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty way to do it is, (my way) -->

```
select * into yournewtable from youroldtable order by yourIdentityColumn;
```

Then, open up yournewtable's design, make sure yourIdentityColumn is Identity(1,1).

Then, drop youroldtable.

Then, rename yournewtable to youroldtable!  ta-da!

Answer (score -1):

```
Set identity_insert Table off;
Update Table set ID = 3 where ID = 4;
...
Set identity_insert Table on;
```

Where Table name is *Table*