# SQL update id all table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table row `idenntifyID` type varchar, I want set values `ID 01`, `ID 02`, `ID 03` it's possible with only SQL ? now is `ID 200`, `ID 654` etc, I want change that will be from 1 to n

Comment: Usually changing Ids makes not a lot of sense beside looking "nice" which is a bad reason. Might I ask why do you want to do this?

Comment: Because I create table from scrath and it's not id it's identify key of something I cant it change

Comment: Did you have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740358/mysql-reorder-reset-auto-increment-primary-key

Comment: Is this an auto-increment key? Is the content of the field ID 01 or just 1 ?

If it is an auto-increment key you can't. The only ways are to create a new table with the auto increment key starting at 1 and copy all the data - leaving out the key - from the old table to the new one, or drop the primary key column and create it again.
More info on auto increment keys: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16691885/1297603) also on comments about why reseeding ID's is not usually recommended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out the links

[How to Auto Increment ID Numbers with Letters and Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14680122/how-to-auto-increment-id-numbers-with-letters-and-numbers)

and

[MySQL auto increment plus alphanumerics in one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380923/mysql-auto-increment-plus-alphanumerics-in-one-column)

OR

If you need to display "ID" with numbers for user viewing purpose just use your application to add it to your auto-increment field when displaying data.