# Collections of ordered groups with ordered items

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to implement this data structure (i'm using PostgreSQL 9.5):

- collection#1

  - image#1 (images in the root of collection)
  - image#2
  - group#1 (group in collection)

    - image#1
    - image#2
  - group#2

    - image#1
- collection#2...

`images` can live in the root of any `Collection` and in `Groups`.
Both `Groups` and `Images` must be ordered in context of parent `Group/Collection`.

I have following tables (i am ready to change them in any way in order to get the best results):

```
CREATE TABLE Collections (
  col_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  col_name VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE Groups (
  group_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  group_collection INT REFERENCES Collections (col_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  group_name VARCHAR(100),
  group_index SERIAL -- Index of group in a collection
);

CREATE TABLE Images (
  image_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  image_collection INT REFERENCES Collections (col_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  image_group INT REFERENCES Groups (group_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  image_url VARCHAR(512),
  image_index SERIAL -- Index of image in a group
);
```

There is no problem to `SELECT` the content of any Collection, but i have problems with adding, removing and reordering of `Images` and `Groups`. Of course i want to keep unique index (ordering) in any `Group/Collection` (order can have any breaks inside like [1, 4, 10] but cannot have repeated values like [1, 1, 3]).

**Update with sample data.** Here is the link to [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/24900/1) with sample data and queries. I'm using this `SELECT` request and it is ok (it gives me required output):

```
SELECT
  Groups.*,
  json_agg(Images.*) as images
FROM Groups
RIGHT JOIN Images
  ON Groups.group_id = Images.image_group
WHERE Groups.group_collection = 1 OR Images.image_collection = 1
GROUP BY Groups.group_id;
```

My main problem is in reordering `Images` (especially moving `Image` from one `Group` to a specific place into another `Group`).

**Note!** Sorry for (maybe) intersecting concepts of *order* and *group* as SQL world also has these concepts but i have no idea how to tell the same things with other words.

Comment: Please add some sample data (e.g. as `insert into`) and the expected output based on that sample data (as formatted text)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for your response! I have added a link to sqlfiddle in my update.

Comment: Perhaps something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607998/using-a-sort-order-column-in-a-database-table/8608085#8608085