# How to maintain

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-design

I'm wondering if SQL Server (i.e. the T-SQL language) has a natural way of doing this or if I have to write fancy constraints/triggers.

Suppose I have a table

```
       RebuplicanCandidates
===================================
 Id |      Name       | ByteIndex
===================================
 1  | 'Marco Rubio'   |    0
 2  | 'Jeb Bush'      |    1
 3  | 'Donald Trump'  |    2
 4  | 'Ted Cruz'      |    3
```

and I remove JebBush:

```
DELETE FROM [RepublicanCandidates] WHERE [Id]=2
```

Then I want the table to be like

```
       RebuplicanCandidates
===================================
 Id |      Name       | ByteIndex
===================================
 1  | 'Marco Rubio'   |    0
 3  | 'Donald Trump'  |    1
 4  | 'Ted Cruz'      |    2
```

Notice that the `ByteIndex` column shuffled.

And then if I insert a candidate

```
INSERT INTO [RepublicanCandidates] (Name) VALUES ('CarlyFiorina')
```

the table becomes

```
       RebuplicanCandidates
===================================
 Id |      Name       | ByteIndex
===================================
 1  | 'Marco Rubio'   |    0
 3  | 'Donald Trump'  |    1
 4  | 'Ted Cruz'      |    2
 5  | 'Carly Fiorina' |    3
```

Comment: ehm....what happened with the inserted row?

Comment: @Lamak Oops, there you go

Comment: Why do you have to store a ByteIndex with no gaps? Deleting the first row would mean that all other rows in the table have to be updated.

Comment: If you created a VIEW based on the table, you could add a row_number() function instead of the ByteIndex column.

Comment: I have to wonder what value there is to having an _unstable_ numbering of `RebuplicanCandidates` _[sic]_ in the database might be? It might be useful for an application to display candidates with dense (?!) numbers assigned, but that is a matter for the application. You couldn't go back and determine who was "14" (and whether they would sell you a pizza) without keeping a complete history of the wandering values and knowing _when_ the "14" was of interest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a sort order column in a database table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607998/using-a-sort-order-column-in-a-database-table)

Answer (score 4):

If you created a VIEW based on the table, you could add a row_number() function, and drop the ByteIndex column from the base table.

```
CREATE VIEW vRebuplicanCandidates
AS

SELECT id, name , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) - 1 AS ByteIndex
FROM RebuplicanCandidates
```

Comment: But ROW_NUMBER() does not guarantee any particular order to rows.

Answer (score 0):

T-SQL cannot do what your are asking.  You will have to write some code or the suggestion in the other answer by is a good one IMHO.